# NEVPNManager check is connected after restart the app?

Tags: ios, networkextension, nevpnmanager

I coding a **VPN** tool, using the `NetworkExtension` framework. I can connect **IPSec** through `NEVPNManager.sharedManager`, and can grab the notification when **VPN** connect status changed. But when I kill the app, and reopen it, the `NEVPNManager.Connect.Status` always Zero, than means can't display the correct connect state. How to solve it?

Comment: After you kill your app do you still see the [VPN] indicator in the status bar?

Comment: yes, the VPN still connecting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    // Register to be notified of changes in the status. These notifications only work when app is in foreground.
    notificationObserver = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(NEVPNStatusDidChangeNotification, object: nil , queue: nil) {
       notification in

       print("received NEVPNStatusDidChangeNotification")

       let nevpnconn = notification.object as! NEVPNConnection
       let status = nevpnconn.status
       self.checkNEStatus(status)
    }
}



func checkNEStatus( status:NEVPNStatus ) {
    switch status {
    case NEVPNStatus.Invalid:
      print("NEVPNConnection: Invalid")
    case NEVPNStatus.Disconnected:
      print("NEVPNConnection: Disconnected")
    case NEVPNStatus.Connecting:
      print("NEVPNConnection: Connecting")
    case NEVPNStatus.Connected:
      print("NEVPNConnection: Connected")
    case NEVPNStatus.Reasserting:
      print("NEVPNConnection: Reasserting")
    case NEVPNStatus.Disconnecting:
      print("NEVPNConnection: Disconnecting")
  }
}
```

The above code should generate the following messages when running the app with VPN already connected:

```
checkNEStatus:  NEVPNConnection: Invalid  
viewDidLoad:    received NEVPNStatusDidChangeNotification  
checkNEStatus:  NEVPNConnection: Connected
```

Comment: I have do this, In my viewController, the code is`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(VPNStatusChanged:) name:NEVPNStatusDidChangeNotification object:nil];
    
    // the status always NEVPNStatusInvalid ...
    NSLog(@"vpn status is %ld", [NEVPNManager sharedManager].connection.status);` and I can observe the state. but if kill the app, and reopen, the state always invalid.

Comment: got it ! must load the vpn config before the notification, and then the NEVPNStatusDidChangeNotification worked ! thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you retaining the NSObjectProtocol returned from addObserver? My previous snippet doesn't show it but I have:
    `var notificationObserver:NSObjectProtocol?`
as a class var in the view controller

Comment: just saw your comment, glad to help.

Comment: I'm experiencing wrong sorting on notification ... the last notification doesn't reflect the current VPN status. Is it possible?

Answer (score 9):

**William Sterling** comment does make sense, & it works for me,

Before adding observer for `NEVPNStatusDidChange` load preferences for VPN Manager object like bellow,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.vpnManager.loadFromPreferences { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error.debugDescription)
            }
            else{
                print("No error from loading VPN viewDidLoad")
            }
        }

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.VPNStatusDidChange(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.NEVPNStatusDidChange, object: nil)

     }
```